# Multiple tomcat instances update - HOW TO?

Tags: tomcat, updates, tomcat8

I have server with multiple tomcat instances running. But all of them have been installed manually.

Now I need to do an upate all of them. My opinion is download latest tomcat version 8.5.35.

Delete all old lib folder per tomcat and link the latest bin folder per each tomcat from latest tomcat version 8.5.35.

Is it good idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest  is to use a Tomcat-Home directory and a Tomcat-Base Directory.

$CATALINA_HOME
$CATALINA_BASE

Just change CATALINA_HOME to new location and restart .
You can refer configration changes below :
http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-85.html#Upgrading_8.5.x